# Does the Google Nexus 7 support external keyboards?

Tags: hardware, nexus-7, external-keyboard

Can I use an external keyboard with a Google Nexus 7? Will the Nexus pair with an Apple Wireless keyboard? Are there other companies that make compatible keyboards?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an external Bluetooth or USB keyboard with the Nexus 7. For more information see the [Connect to keyboards, mice, & other devices](http://support.google.com/nexus/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2583236) section of the Nexus 7 manual. [Mike Elgan reports](https://plus.google.com/113117251731252114390/posts/W5eMiKrMQjM) that the Nexus 7 also works with an Apple Bluetooth keyboard.